# Why i can use git-daemon serve my git repo?

Tags: git, git-daemon

There are some git bare repo in `/home/git/repositories` dir.
I use `git-daemon-run` serve git protocol to access these repos.
For example `/home/git/repositories/root/spider.git` is a bare git repo.

This is command `ps -ef | grep git` result.

```
120       9638  1062  0 10:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-daemon --verbose --reuseaddr --base-path=/home/git/repositories --export-all --max-connections=64 -- /home/git/repositories
```

When I exec `git clone git://hostname/root/spider.git`, I get :

```
Cloning into 'spider'...
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /root/spider.git
```

I check the syslog `/var/log/git-daemon/current`, I get :

```
2013-03-08_02:56:02.42145 [9698] Connection from 127.0.0.1:60080
2013-03-08_02:56:02.42149 [9698] Extended attributes (22 bytes) exist <host=hostname>
2013-03-08_02:56:02.42186 [9698] Request upload-pack for '/root/spider.git'
2013-03-08_02:56:02.42189 [9698] '/home/git/repositories/root/spider.git' does not appear to be a git repository
2013-03-08_02:56:02.42221 [9638] [9698] Disconnected (with error)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, double check your path and make sure you did a

```
cd /home/git/repositories/root/
git init --bare spider
```

If that repo already existed, but directly in '`/home/git/repositories`', then you would need to adapt your `git clone` command:

```
 git clone git://hostname/spider.git
```

---

Finally, **make sure the process git-daemon has the right to access the repository**.

The account running the git-dameon must be able to access `/home/git/repositories/root/sipder.git`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but the problem is not resolve yet.I did double check the path and adapt my command.

Comment: @王振威 then is it a right issue? Does the process has the right to access `/home/git/repositories/root/sipder.git`? Is that bare repo protected for root?

Comment: Thank you!The reson is that the process has no permission to access the repo,I have resolved it!

Comment: @王振威 Excellent. I have included that in the answer, for more visibility, and for you to select.

Answer (score 4):

Add  `--enable=receive-pack` to the `git daemon` command line, to enable `send-pack` ([manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack)) support. You will then need to `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the `fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported` error for me. This seems to be required if you want to `git push` without using any authentication. It basically enables anonymous push.

Answer (score 1):

Create a empty file called git-daemon-export-ok in the repo dir.

Comment: In the original question mentioned `--export-all` deals with that.